# destiny 2 cross save ps4 and pc

Tags: destiny-2

for my ps4, I have the forsaken DLC, and I wanted to cross save to my pc (which has Forsaken and Shadowkeep). The question is, will I have access to the Shadowkeep missions and content if my main account is my ps4 account which doesn't have Shadowkeep?

Answer (score 1):

You will **not** be able to access Shadowkeep-specific content, such as bounties from Eris Morn etc, except on the platform where you purchased the DLC. From the [FAQ](https://www.bungie.net/7/en/CrossSave):

> Do my previous game purchases transfer across platforms? Destiny 2
> expansions (ex: Forsaken, Shadowkeep) do not transfer between
> platforms with Cross Save. Destiny 2 Season Passes (ex: Season of the
> Undying) do move between platforms on the characters they were
> redeemed on.

I have the same issue, as I own Forsaken and Shadowkeep on Xbox but Beyond Light on PlayStation. I switch back to Xbox sometimes, mainly to pick up missions or purchase certain Exotics.